# Is it possible to get back the inserted shape id / inline picture id when running SetSelectedDataAsync on using the office-js Common API?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

Is it possible to get back the inserted shape id / inline picture id when running SetSelectedDataAsync on using the office-js Common API?

I can't see many code examples of callback functions where this is handled?

Comment: What is in the [AsyncResult.value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.asyncresult#value) property in the callback?

Comment: As I know, there is no such function for SetSelectedDataAysnc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  This is not possible.